# Enabling GL EXT_blend_minmax

Tags: three.js, webgl, opengl-es-2.0, webgl-extensions

According to [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EXT_blend_minmax) `EXT_blend_minmax` has been supported since Chrome 38 and Firefox 47.

I'm trying to use it from Three.js. However, it doesn't work for me with either latest Chrome or latest Firefox:

```
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
const gl = renderer.getContext();
const ext = gl.getExtension('EXT_blend_minmax');

console.log(ext) // -> null; I'm hoping for { [...], MAX_EXT }
```

I've also tried setting my Chrome WebGL flags to experimental, but I get the same result.

Is there something I should do to activate it?

---

*X/Y reason*: I would like multiple semi-transparent objects to overlap. However, I want a max alpha limit among them. My understanding is that `EXT_blend_minmax` can help achieve this. Example visuals:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to explicitly request the `EXT_blend_minmax` extension on app level. If you configure the blending equation with the `three.js` constants `THREE.MinEquation` or `THREE.MaxEquation`, you can use the extension automatically.

Blending is defined for materials so you have to set the `blendEquation` property to one of the above values.

Comment: Ah, thanks Mugen! I was looking for the constants within the renderer context so I missed it.